# extracting unicode text from mysql to java

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, console

I have a table 'test' in my database with a column 'msg' that stores strings in various languages like English, Hindi, Telugu, etc.
These strings are displayed properly in the database.
But if i extract it into my java code and print it on the console using `system.out.println` , it shows **?????????** instead of the actual string.

Is this because the font used in eclipse console does not support these scripts? If so, how can i change the font to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot print the UTF-8 characters on console with its default settings. Make sure the console you use to display the output is also encoded in UTF-8.

> In Eclipse for example, you need to go to Run Configuration > Common
>   -> Encoding -> Select UTF-8 from dropdown.

[image]

Comment: yeah.. it seems i can accept it as an answer only after 5 more minutes

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `characterEncoding=UTF-8` parameter to the end of your JDBC connection URL. Even set the table and column character set to *UTF-8.* This [article](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases) explains how to do that.

Also change the Eclipse console Output encoding using

> Run Configuration > Common -> Encoding