# Unicode characters in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

I'm trying to print nice yin-yang from my Java program:

```
System.out.println("\u262f");
```

Everything is OK in Netbeans (default settings): both yin-yang and other stuff in English is printed correctly. What should I do to make Eclipse to do the same? With default Eclipse setting I get only "?".

I tried to change Console Encoding in Run Dialog like suggested in 
[extracting unicode text from mysql to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145619/extracting-unicode-text-from-mysql-to-java), but things get even worse (more precisely, this is output: 剅䐍੓瑯瀡ഊⴱ‍਍ਿഊ奅䱌佗ഊ坡楴ഊ〠ഊഊ㼍ੇ剅䕎ഊ奯甠捡渠杯ഊ〠ഊഊ㼍� - which one is yin-yang??).

Any suggestions?

Comment: the yin-yang characters that create you problem are hardcoded in the java file, or on the database ?

Comment: In java file: "\u262f".

Comment: have you tried my answer to see if it work?

Comment: Yes, thanks! See below, still the same :(

Comment: You need to clarify your question, what excact code you execute, what you get in ecilpse, what you get in netbeans, what you expected instead, etc ...

Comment: System.out.println("\u262f"); (with main() etc., of course)
☯ - Netbeans
? - Eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In eclipse this prints the ying-yang for me

```
System.out.println(new String(Character.toChars(9775)));
```

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Workspace->TextFileEncoding, set it to UTF-8

Comment: The same result "?". I suppose what you suggested should work the same way as Run Dialog settings, and it does.

Comment: Still "?". 
OK, no big deal, I guess something wrong with my Eclipse. Anyway, I'll probably abandon it (after I found out that to move Undo into Toolbar I have to install some plugin, come on...).

Comment: During setting the Encoding consider to set particular OS also

Answer (score 3):

For change the default console enconding, add the next line in your `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```