# Printing Japanese does not work, despite Java now using UTF-be 8 by default

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, console

I have Eclipse 2022, which now has UTF-8 as default, and I'm trying to print Japanese characters. Such as:

```
System.out.println("わ");
```

The problem is that in the console, it just prints out `?` marks. The closest thing I found to someone having the same problem as me would be:
[UTF-8 text (Hindi) not getting displayed on Browser window or Eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772275/)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536489/4222206

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Java's UTF-8 support. `String` and `println()` always already correctly supported Unicode out of the box.

The result of this solely depends on whether your console supports Unicode or not. I suspect you used **Windows CMD**, which does **not support Unicode** by default.

Also see: [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/)

---

The mentioned *"UTF-8 by default"* feature is for stuff like `new FileReader(...)` or `new String(...)`, APIs that defaulted to the platform's default encoding in the past.

Comment: How would I fix this would I do this threw the eclipse setting or threw some kind command prompt

Comment: Your Java code is correct. Your console lacks unicode support, thats all. Either use a different console or adjust your console settings as explained in the linked thread.

Comment: Or the console has unicode support but isn't using a font that includes that glyph.